# I'm trying to determine a big O notation for the following - just wanted to confirm if this method makes sense?

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I'm trying to determine a big O notation for the following code snippet - just wanted to confirm if this method makes sense?

```
1 public static int func3(int[ ] arr) { 
2   int n = arr.length, total = 0; 
3   for (int j=0; j < n; j++) // loop from 0 to n-1 
4     for (int k=0; k <= j; k++) // loop from 0 to j 
5       total += arr[j]; 
6   return total; 
7 }
```

If I let lines 2 and 6 be $a$ they are evaluated 1 times,

line 3 be $b$ which is evaluated $n+1$ times

line 4 be $c$ which is evaluated $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+2)$ times

line 5 be $d$ which is evaluated $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(i+1)$ times

I end up getting:
$$a+(n+1)b + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}[(i+2)c+(i+1)d]$$
$$a+(n+1)b + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}[2c+d+i(c+d)]$$
$$a+(n+1)b + 2cn + dn + (c+d) \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}[i]$$
$$a+(n+1)b + 2cn + dn + (c+d)\cdot \frac{n}{2}\cdot(n-1)$$
$$a+(n+1)b + 2cn + dn + (c+d)\cdot \frac{n^2-n}{2}$$
$$2a+2bn+2b + 4cn + 2dn + cn^2 -cn+dn^2 -dn$$
$$n^2(c+d)+n(2b+3c+d)+2a+2b$$
Therefore a big-Oh characterization,in terms of n, of the running time is $O(n^2)$

Comment: It's correct, but somewhat elaborate.

Comment: $O(n^2)$ is correct for nested 2 cycles, though for me is not fully clear estimations for c and d.